# Switch top bar with animation (Android)

Tags: android, animation, layout

[Demo Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSCF7.png)

Is there anyway to switch the second layout to first layout by sliding effects?

I want to set button onclick then slide the layout. I tried many ways but can't manage to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_from_left);
            anim1.setDuration(1000); // set how long you want the animation

Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide_to_right);
            anim2.setDuration(1000); // set how long you want the animation

firstlayout.setAnimation(anim1);
secondlayout.setAnimation(anim2);
secondlayout.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
```

I manage to get the result using above codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check this out: https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations. It contains great examples of material transitions and animations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any solution without using third party?

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
 this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter,
               R.anim.animation_leave)
```

//

```html
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:shareInterpolator="false">
                <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
                 </set>
```

Comment: If I wanna go for the transition in layout only? Because seems like this solution used for make the animation when start a new Intent.

Comment: you can use animation for this  use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: its big concept